# asset module: how to import assets?

Tags: media

I try the asset module.

But wonder if there is a way to import a bunch of images (and other types)?

Cannot figure out, I have all submodules enabled.

There is way in drupal5. I use d7

Comment: A way to do this would be to use Migrate module, but it is a bit over-engineered.

Comment: yep, migrate is too much for now. But I found a way, needs a bit testing though. Maybe I can post an answer asap.